# AngularJS template not updating until browser interaction

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-components, angularjs-templates

I'm having hard time figuring this one out so I'll try to explain it as best as I can.

I have a service like so

```
export class Users {
    constructor(private Api) {}

    public async getUsers() {
        return this.Api.get('/users');
    }
}
```

In my component I'm using it like this

```
export const myComponent = {
    template: '<pre>{{$ctrl.users|json}}</pre>',
    controller: class MyComponent implements IController {
        public users: any[] = [];

        constructor(private Users) {}

        public $onInit() {
            this.fetchUsers();
        }

        public async fetchUsers() {
            this.users = await this.Users.getUsers();
            console.log(this.users);
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the console.log working just fine but the template does not update until I interact with the browser somehow e.g. click something or press a key. What is going on? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don’t use async / await. It breaks change detection

Comment: The ES6 promises created by `async`/`await` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.